# MySQL: Combining two SELECT statements to show only intersecting rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm building a search function where I have to combine two SELECT statements and show only intersecting rows (i.e. rows that would appear in both SELECT statements if they were run individually).

For example, say I have two tables.

One is called `fruits` and the other called `vegetables`. Each table has ten rows.

The first statement...

```
SELECT * FROM `fruits` WHERE 1
```

... would show all 10 fruits.

The second statement...

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM fruits t1, vegetables t2
WHERE t1.`color` = t2.`color`
```

... would show 2 fruits.

If I combine these two select statements like so...

```
SELECT * FROM `fruits` WHERE 1
UNION
SELECT t1.*
FROM fruits t1, vegetables t2
WHERE t1.`color` = t2.`color`
```

... the results show all 10 fruits, which is not what I want.

So how do I modify the above statement so that it will only show intersecting rows (which should give me 2 fruits)?

**Im required to keep the first SELECT statement intact** and join a second SELECT statement to produce only the intersecting rows. This is because I'm modifying an existing search function.

Thanks very much!

EDIT: From a bit of googling, I understand that what I want could be achieved using INTERSECT, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `fruits` WHERE 1
INTERSECT
SELECT t1.*
FROM fruits t1, vegetables t2
WHERE t1.`color` = t2.`color`
```

But that's MS SQL. How do I accomplish the above...

1. Using MySQL?
2. While keeping the first SELECT statement intact?

Comment: What is the expected `right results`?

Comment: What is problem with second statement...

Comment: @xdazz, the expected results is 2 rows. Reason I need to join two SELECT statements together is because I'm modifying an existing search function, which requires me to keep the first SELECT statement intact.

Comment: If you only want intersecting rows, UNION certainly forms no part of the solution.

Comment: @EJP, yes, intersecting rows is what I need. I don't have to use UNION. But I'm required to keep the first SELECT statement intact (it's part of the requirement) because I'm modifying an existing search function. So how do I join these two SELECT statements together to produce the intersecting rows? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> So how do I modify the above statement so that it will only show
>   overlapped rows (which should give me 2 fruits)?

Isn't the below query just give you the right result?

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM fruits t1, vegetables t2
WHERE t1.`color` = t2.`color`
```

It's inner join, you could rewrite it to:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM fruits t1
INNER JOIN vegetables t2 ON t1.`color` = t2.`color`
```

Comment: Reason I need to join two SELECT statements together is because I'm modifying an existing search function, which requires me to keep the first SELECT statement intact. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM `fruits` WHERE 1) t1
INNER JOIN vegetables t2 ON t1.`color` = t2.`color`
```